# Returning count of more persons

Tags: python

I am new in python and I have problem in my code. My function count_transitive_sellers_with_degree is returning count only from person sellers. I need to get it return count of person sellers and seller sellers and so on. I do not know how to write it.. Could you help me and say where it is a problem? Thank you :)

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, year_of_birth, degree):
        self.name = name
        self.year_of_birth = year_of_birth
        self.degree = degree
        self.leader = None
        self.sellers = []

def create_leadership(leader, seller):
    seller.leader = leader
    leader.sellers.append(seller)

def count_transitive_sellers_with_degree(person, degree):
    count = 0
    for seller in person.sellers:
        if seller.degree == degree:
            count += 1 + count_transitive_sellers_with_degree(seller,degree)
    return count

>>> martin = Person('Martin', 1991, 'phd')
>>> tom = Person('Tom', 1993, 'mgr')
>>> josh = Person('Josh', 1995, 'bc')
>>> create_leadership(martin, tom)
>>> create_leadership(tom, josh)
>>> count_transitive_sellers_with_degree(martin, 'bc')
```

what it should write... -> 1

what it is writing now... -> 0

Comment: When you used a debugger, at what point did the behavior differ from what you expected?

Comment: well I try it with tom = Person('Tom', 1993, 'bc') and it counts right.. so I realized that it is not counting the other sellers...

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're only calling count_transitive_sellers_with_degree on sellers who themselves have the degree you're testing for, I haven't tested the below, but I think it should work.

```
def count_transitive_sellers_with_degree(person, degree):
    count = 0
    for seller in person.sellers:
        if seller.degree == degree:
            count += 1 
        # A seller's sellers should be counted irrespective of
        # if they have the degree or not
        count += count_transitive_sellers_with_degree(seller,degree)
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here. Your if condition is not allowing you to go the recursive part as Tom's degree is not 'bc'.

```
if seller.degree == degree:
            count += 1 + count_transitive_sellers_with_degree(seller,degree)
```

Comment: Should I add something more to the if condition?

Comment: Bring the recursive part out of the if condition

Answer (score 0):

```
if seller.degree == degree:
```

does not reflect what you say your program is supposed to do: it will only add the children of the person if they have the same degree